# Ajax request response not displaying on div section

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, view, response

Ajax Request response doesn't not display on div section. However, it show on the network tab . 
Here is my my JQuery code.

```
function FetchUserEscort(){
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                url   : 'Home/FetchUserEscort',
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += 
                '<div class="col-lg-4">'+
                    '<div class="user-block block text-center">'+
                        '<div class="avatar"><img src="uassets/img/avatar-4.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid">'+
                            '<div class="order dashbg-1">'+ i +'</div>'+
                         '</div><a href="#" class="user-title">'+
                            '<h3 class="h5">'+data[i].ProfileName+'</h3><span>'+data[i].ContactNo+'</span></a>'+
                        '<div class="contributions"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View More</button></div>'+
                        '<div class="details d-flex">'+
                            '<div class="item"><i class="icon-info"></i><strong>80</strong></div>'+
                            '<div class="item"><i class="fa fa-gg"></i><strong>420</strong></div>'+
                            '<div class="item"><i class="icon-flow-branch"></i><strong>272</strong></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
                    }
                    $('#ViewData').html(html);
                }
 
            });
        }
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row" id="ViewData" >
</div>
```

Comment: What is data.length? can you alert that? alert(data.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var html = '';

html="

hello world

"

$('#ViewData').append(html);

try it..